# Dynamic JPA Entities

Tags: jpa-2.0

I'm using EJB and JPA to develop a Java EE project. The server is Jboss AS 7.1 which uses Hibernate as the JPA provider.

In this project I'd like to add many new tables to the database. I'd also like to add many new columns to these tables *at run-time*. After these columns have been added, I'll add 、delete or select data in the table  (at run-time as well).

How can I do this with JPA?

Comment: Can refer here - http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Dynamic for EclipseLink.

Comment: I'm also don't know how to do. Do you can give a example?

Comment: I haven't tried, but the link is quite informative, you can go through it & try yourself.